# Cumulative condition query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1:

```
ID      Total1 Total2 Total3
1         10       0          20
1         40       0          50
1         15       0          5
```

Table 2:

```
ID     Total

1        140
```

How do i add cumulatively all the rows and find the matching total in table2?

How do i add cumulatively all the rows and find the NOT matching total in table2 and write update statement to update (add those) and write to table2 ?

```
select sum(t1.total1) + sum(t1.total2) +sum(t1.total3) as "Total" from
table t1, table t2 where t1.ID=t2.ID and  sum(t1.total1) +
sum(t1.total2) +sum(t1.total3)=t2.total;
```

I am not able to get it correctly the update syntax.

Comment: You are missing a `GROUP BY ID` in there, no?

Comment: can you describe what the query should do in the scenario you presented (what is the expected output)?

Comment: What do you mean by "the update syntax"? Are you trying to update another table with the totals? Or are you trying to perform a join? Your question is ambiguous. Also please do not use old-style inner joins (`from a, b where a.something = b.something`). Explicit `INNER JOIN` syntax is preferred and less problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have the right query to find the totals and match them up.  To update rows that don't have the same total, you could use a correlated subquery like this:

```
UPDATE table2
SET total = (
   SELECT SUM(Total1 + Total2 + Total3) FROM table1
   WHERE id = table2.id
   GROUP BY id
)
```

Or with a join (slightly more complicated, but likely faster)

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.total = t1.total
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT id, SUM(Total1 + Total2 + Total3) as total FROM table1
   GROUP BY id
) t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.total <> t1.total
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select T1.* from
(
    select t1.ID, sum(t1.total1) + sum(t1.total2) + sum(t1.total3) as Total
    from table t1
    group by t1.ID
) t1
inner join table t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.Total = t2.total
```